# Prove that the ring of real quaternions modulo $p$ is not a division ring.

Tags: ring-theory, division-ring

Using the ring of real quaternions as a model, we define the quaternions over the integers $\text{mod}$ $p,$ $p$ an odd prime number, in exactly the same way; however, now considering all symbols of the form $a_0 + a_1i + a_2j + a_3k,$ where $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$
are integers mod $p.$ Prove that $R$ is not a division ring.

I tried solving this problem as follows:

This ring is said to be a division ring, if, the non-zero elements of the ring, form a group under multiplication.

Closure, Idenity and Associative property is satisfied in $R$ as $1+0i+0j+0k$ is the identity element.

We need to show that the inverse of all the non-zero elements doesn't necessarily exist.
If possible, let $a^{-1}=b$ exist and be equal to $b=b_0+b_1i+b_2j+b_3k.$

We note that,

$$ab=(a_0+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k)(b_0+b_1i+b_2j+b_3k)=(a_0b_0-a_1b_1-a_2b_2-a_3b_3)\pmod p+i(a_0b_1+a_1b_0+a_2b_3-a_3b_2)\pmod p+j(a_0b_2-a_1b_3+a_2b_0+a_3b_1)\pmod p+k(a_0b_3+a_1b_2-a_2b_1+a_3b_0)\pmod p.$$

Now, as $b$ is the inverse of $a$ so, $$(a_0b_0-a_1b_1-a_2b_2-a_3b_3)\pmod p=1,$$$$(a_0b_1+a_1b_0+a_2b_3-a_3b_2)\pmod p=0,$$$$(a_0b_2-a_1b_3+a_2b_0+a_3b_1)\pmod p=0,$$ $$(a_0b_3+a_1b_2-a_2b_1+a_3b_0)\pmod p=0\tag 1.$$

To prove the asserted claim, we have to show that the system $(1)$ does not always have a solution in $a_i,b_i$.

---

But this is actually, the point, where I am stuck. I dont understand how to proceed further.

Comment: You don't need "to show that the system (1) does not always have a solution". You only have to find one example of an element which doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: @MasB And, unfortunately I am unable to find it.

Comment: Use [Lagrange's four square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) to write $p=a_0^2+a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2$ where $0\le a_i<p$. What can you say about $q=a_0+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k$? In particular, what is $q\overline{q}$ where $\overline{q}=a_0-a_1i-a_2j-a_3k$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop The link you attached looks interesting. But I'll be glad if you consider elaborating that what sort of inference should I make upon $a_0+a_1i+a_2j+a_3k$ ?

Comment: Well, you will see that $q\overline{q}=0$ but $q\ne 0$ and $\overline{q}\ne 0$ in that ring.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Ok, and? Better, if you provide a formal answer. I think you have a much eadier way, under your sleeves :)

Comment: @ThomasFinley Then $q$ cannot be invertible. Otherwise $\bar{q} = q^{-1}q\bar{q} = q^{-1} \cdot 0 = 0$, contradiction!

Comment: Basically, _a zero divisor cannot be invertible_ in a ring with unity.

Comment: One example is already given in the comments to the OP's https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748589/show-that-the-possible-ideals-of-a-ring-of-quaternions-over-integers-modulo-an-o